# How i get a Logfile from my Powershellscript

Tags: powershell

I would like to record all my inputs and outputs of my Powershell script into a logfile. I've tried a function, but I have to write the function in each line. I have test it with a Start-transcript, I dont know, but I think its only for Errors, it doesn't work really good. 
It is possible, if I start my script to get a Log all lines?

for Example:

```
$u=rene
New-AdUser -Name $u ...
Write-Hoste "New User ist Create $u"
```

and in my log file should stand:

```
17.01.2018 13:00 $u=rene
17.01.2018 13:00 New-AdUser -Name $u ...
17.01.2018 13:00 Write-Hoste "New User ist Create $u"
```

... and everything else (for Example Errors)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to log the entire script, then you could do something like this

```
@(
$u=rene
New-AdUser -Name $u ...
Write-Hoste "New User ist Create $u"
... Rest of your script
) | Out-file -FilePath \\PathToYourLogFile\Logfile.txt"
```

That is one way of doing it. One more way of doing it would be using the `Start-Transcript` at the beginning of your script and ending your script with `Stop-Transcript` cmdlet and redirecting the output to a text fie. See [start-transcript](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.host/start-transcript?view=powershell-5.1) and [stop-transcript](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.host/stop-transcript?view=powershell-5.1) for details.

I found one example that will create a daily log for your script (if you run it multiple times a day it'll just append to what you have).  The log will be in the same folder as your script and it'll clean out any logs older than 15 days.

```
$VerbosePreference = "Continue"
$LogPath = Split-Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
Get-ChildItem "$LogPath\*.log" | Where LastWriteTime -LT (Get-Date).AddDays(-15) | Remove-Item -Confirm:$false
$LogPathName = Join-Path -Path $LogPath -ChildPath "$($MyInvocation.MyCommand.Name)-$(Get-Date -Format 'MM-dd-yyyy').log"
Start-Transcript $LogPathName -Append
```

Then at the end of your script, just add

```
Stop-Transcript
```

[Here](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/1233789-add-logging-to-powershell-script) is the link for the same.
If you want to log specific things then you could use `Out-File` cmdlet at specific and desired places. Hope that helps!

Comment: If i use Transcript, he writes only one log if he had a mistake, if I have created a new user without errors then he writes nothing in the log. The orginal Script is bigger and the its to many work to add on every line the out-file

Comment: That's because there is no error encountered if a user is created successfully. If you want that in the log too, you would need to add an extra custom message to your script. Something like, `write-output "User created successfully!"`

Comment: yes thats right, but i will a log that logs all from start to stop. All Messages from Creat or success to error.